# Display List of Custom Post Type in Custom Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I created custom post type "Projects" with 3 fields(Name, Title, Technology) in Admin Panel and Added a List of Projects.

I want to display the list of projects in my custom theme.

Can you give me a better Reference to understand and Integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get an array of posts, limited to your custom post type.  I would use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, // -1 here will return all posts
    'post_type'        => 'project', //your custom post type
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);
$projects = get_posts( $args );

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    printf('<div><a href="%s">%s</a></div>',
            get_permalink($project->ID),
            $project->post_title);
}
```

Comment: Can get particular Project By mention the Id, Like Where condition.?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)´ to do a query and display the results:

```
<?php 
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; //pagination
   $args = array(
        'paged'           => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'  => 12, //or any other number
        'post_type'       => 'Projects' //your custom post type
        );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); // The Query 

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {  // The Loop

       echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();

           echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; //shows the title of the post (Project)
        }
       echo '</ul>';

       /* Restore original Post Data */
          wp_reset_postdata();

    } else {
       // no posts found
    }
```

This code displays the "Projects" in an unordered list, but you could use any other HTML (div, ol, article...)